# "/usr/local/bin/expo-cli: No such file or directory" error after downloading expo-cli

Tags: bash, permissions, command-line-interface, expo

While trying to update expo-cli I deleted expo-cli from /bin
Evidently, this is not something I was supposed to do, now I can't run expo at all.

attempting to run `npm install -g expo-cli` seems like it works, but then I still can't actually run expo.
`which expo-cli` returns nothing and `expo-cli --version` returns a "no such file or directory"

Do I have to manually add it back to path? and how would one do that?

Comment: The command  seems to be `expo`. please, check it.

Answer (score 1):

So, you can use the command

`npm bin --global`

find out where npm installs global executables

and then add that location to your $PATH:

adding a line in your `.profile/.bash_profile/.zprofile` or similar, depending on which shell you use (you can find out what is your default shell using `echo $SHELL`).

```
export PATH=$PATH:/home/Rapprogtrain/bin
#           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ change to the path returned by "npm bin --global"!
```

answer found at https://github.com/expo/expo-cli/issues/663